# Is it good to have a default implementation of all functions of all derived classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am trying to write a code model such that there is a base class and two different classes inherit from it, eg:- animal class with the dog and cat class inheriting

```
Animal* a = new Dog();

playWith(a);
```

now the playWith function will have `animal *` as a parameter and should work with both the dog instance or cat instance and will call various functions that might be exclusive to them such as fetch for dog, or climb for cat

Both dog and cat classes will have some same functions which will be declared and defined in the animal class but there are some functions exclusive to only one

I have made the code work by declaring all the exclusive functions in the animal class also with a virtual keyword and an implementation of just throwing an error

And then I have defined the actual implementation inside the derived classes

Now my question is, Is this a good method to define functions, if not can you suggest some alternative

UPDATE:

A minimal example of what I am trying to do is

```
class Animal {
public:
    void walk(); // all classes are able to call this function and it is inherited from here
    
    virtual void fetch(); // they have an error message such as not implemented
    virtual void climb();
}

class Dog : public Animal {
public    
    void fetch();
}

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    void climb();
}

class Human{ // complex class with other functions also
    void playWith(Animal* a){ // Please note that this might be part of something else such as another class 
         ...
    }
}

int main(){
    Animal a = new Dog();
    Human h = new Human();
    h->playWith(a);
}
```

This currently works with the correct function from derived class being called

UPDATE 2:

Currently I cannot declare them as pure virtual functions as the Cat Class does not know how to fetch and the Dog Class does not climb
and If I declare them to be pure virtual then they will need to defined

Comment: Side note avoid `new`, use 1std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal = std::make_unique<Dog>();`. This will help you avoid memory leaks. `playWith(Animal*)` can keep the (non-owning) raw pointer.  See C++ core guidelines and look for "raw pointers" e.g. [R.7](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning)

Comment: To be able to answer your question we need to see a bit more of your code. E.g. is Animal a (pure) abstract baseclass with virtual methods, does Dog have methods with the override keyword etc. Also see [C.128](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final) with regard to virtual/override/final

Comment: "_I have made the code work by declaring all the exclusive functions in the animal class also_": The _non-exclusive_ functions should be `virtual` functions in the base class (and probably also _pure_ virtual.) The exclusive functions should not need to be declared in the base class at all. Why would they need to be? Someone like `playWith` who takes a `animal*` as argument shouldn't need to know about them. They only care that they get an animal, not that they get any specific type of animal. If `playWith` cares about that it shouldn't take a `animal*` as parameter.

Comment: "I cannot declare them as pure virtual functions as the Cat Class does not know how to fetch and the Dog Class does not climb and If I declare them to be pure virtual then they will need to defined" -> That immediately tells me that neither should be in the interface at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base class is meant to capture commonalities. That said, only `walk` should be declared in `Animal`. From `Animal`, you may further derive other kinds of animals with different capabilities like `fetch` and `climb` like `FetchableAnimal` and `ClimableAnimal`.

Since `playWith` takes an `Animal`, it's expected that `playWith` works with capabilities that all animals share. Since `fetch` and `climb` are exclusive to certain animals, it's a design contradiction if you intend to invoke them in `playWith(Animal*)`. You may consider adding `playWith(FetchableAnimal*)` and `playWith(ClimableAnimal*)` for such cases.

**The bottom line is that base class is supposed to capture feature intersection, not union.**

Answer (score 2):

The alternative you are looking for is a **pure virtual function**.

```
virtual void playWith(animal *) = 0;
```

The compiler will force subclasses to create an implementation, much better than a runtime error. Now, there are other parts of this that don't look stylistically correct. If `playWith` is a method of the `Animal` class (suggest classes start with a capital letter), then there would be no parameter. If it is supposed to have a parameter, with `this` playing with the passed in animal, then I would pass by reference: `playWith(Animal& a)`.

Raw pointer use is also discouraged. Can the other animal be created on the stack? If not, you should consider `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

It's my first typing in stack overflow. After arranging things you are talking, please try the program below I just wrote to see if it can meet what you are thinking.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
public:
    virtual void played_with() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    void played_with() { fetch(); }
private:
    void fetch() { std::cout << "I am fetching.\n"; }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    void played_with() { climb(); }
private:
    void climb() { std::cout << "I am climbing.\n"; }
};

class Human {
public:
    // Reference is more convenient than pointer here.
    void play_with(Animal& a) { a.played_with(); }
};

int main()
{
    Dog d;
    Cat c;
    Human h;
    h.play_with(d);
    h.play_with(c);
    return 0;
}
```

I was using Visual Studio 2022. The output is:

```
I am fetching.
I am climbing.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

One aspect of polymorphism in C++ is to declare your functions as `virtual` and each of your derived classes `override` them as of their need.
Once you instantiate a Dog object, you call its overriden method, as such preventing cross calling other derived classes methods.

Answer (score -4):

Don't put the exclusive functions as virtual functions in the base `animal` class. That's a rather bad design.

Instead create new global functions that take either a `dog` or a `cat` instance, and use *downcasting* to cast the `animal*` pointer to the correct type:

```
dogOnlyFunction(static_cast<dog*>(a));
```

---

While the design, maybe even the requirements and their analysis, seems flawed to begin with, you could solve it with *dynamic* downcasting, which is checked at runtime:

```
void playWith(animal* a)
{
    a->walk();  // Common function

    if (auto d = dynamic_cast<dog*>(a); d != nullptr)
    {
        d->fetch();  // Dog specific function
    }
    else if (auto c = dynamic_cast<cat*>(a); c != nullptr)
    {
        c->climb();  // Cat specific function
    }
}
```

As can be noted from this example, this doesn't scale well when more types are added. So a perhaps better solution is to make a virtual *member* function `playWidth` which is overridden in the child classes and calls their specific functions:

```
struct animal
{
    virtual void playWidth() = 0;
    virtual void walk() = 0;
};

struct dog : public animal
{
    void playWidth() override
    {
        walk();    // Call the common function
        fetch();   // Call the dog specific function
    }

    void walk() override
    {
        // TODO: Walk
    }

    void fetch()
    {
        // TODO: Fetch
    }
};

struct cat : public animal
{
    void playWidth() override
    {
        walk();    // Call the common function
        climb();   // Call the cat specific function
    }

    void walk() override
    {
        // TODO: Walk
    }

    void climb()
    {
        // TODO: Climb
    }
};
```

In the example above I leave the common `walk` function as a pure virtual function in the base class, so that all child-classes needs to override it. If not all child-classes should have a `walk` function, then it could be make class-specific just like `fetch` and `climb`.

Now instead of your global `void playWith(Animal*)` function, just call `a->playWidth();`

Comment: Setting yourself up for runtime errors? Urk.

Comment: can you please elaborate, Say I want to expose only the playWith Function to the user, Should that function call these downcasting functions for dog and cat?

Comment: @Sanchit What is this `playWith` function supposed to do? Why does it need to call type-specific functions? That sounds like a bad design to begin with.

Comment: can you please suggest some alternative then,
 but I am trying to have only one function that will do the same action for both but need different functions

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but again what if the playWith function is part of some other class , eg if it is `human->playWith(Animal*)`,  is the first code block that is casting and checking the only solution?

Comment: @Sanchit Reverse it: `a->playWith(human)` And unless you post your actual and underlying problem, including the full assignment/exercise, we can go around like this for hours and just guess. Please edit your question to tell us the original assignment or exercise, including all requirements and limitations.